# I want to change the jquery radio button to the original color

Tags: html, css

html code

```
<label class="radio-label1"><span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp원&nbsp룸</span>
            <form:radiobutton onclick="test()" class="type-btn" path="market_type" value="1"/>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-label2"><span>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp투&nbsp룸</span>
            <form:radiobutton onclick="test()" class="type-btn" path="market_type" value="2"/>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-label3"><span style="padding-left:15px">&nbsp쓰리룸</span>
            <form:radiobutton onclick="test()" class="type-btn" path="market_type" value="3"/>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-label4"><span style="padding-left:3px">오피스텔</span>
            <form:radiobutton onclick="test()" class="type-btn" path="market_type" value="4"/>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-label5"><span style="margin-left:15px">&nbsp아파트</span>
            <form:radiobutton onclick="test()" class="type-btn" path="market_type" value="5"/>
            </label>
```

jquery code

```
 function test() {
        var obj_value = $("input:radio[name='market_type']:checked").val();     
        $('.radio-label'+obj_value).css('background-color','red');
    }
```

css code

```
.third-radio label{
    width:110px;
    height:40px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-left:15px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    font-size:20px;
}


.type-btn{
    opacity:0;
}
```

I want to restore the color of the unchecked radio button
The label remains red even when the check is released.